# oracle check duplicate value before insert into table

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

I have two functions to check the duplicate value before insert into table, but I do not know which method is more efficient?

First method:

```
select count(*)
      into ln_rec_cnt
      from ieexco_tbl t
     where t.ieexco_dept_code = p_dept
       and NVL(t.IEEXCO_SEQ, '|') = NVL(p_indx, '|')
    if ln_rec_cnt > 0 then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Save coordinator record repeatedly');
    end if;
```

Second method:

```
insert into ieexco_tbl t
            (IEEXCO_DEPT_CODE,
             IEEXCO_SEQ,
             IEEXCO_NAME,
             IEEXCO_PHONE,
             IEEXCO_EMAIL,
             IEEXCO_CREATE_DATE,
             IEEXCO_OPR_PIDM)
 select 
             p_dept,
             p_indx(i),
             p_name(i),
             p_tel(i),
             p_email(i),
             sysdate,
             p_opr_pidm 
from dual 
where not exists(SELECT 1 
                 FROM ieexco_tbl 
                 WHERE IEEXCO_DEPT_CODE = p_dept
                 and NVL(IEEXCO_SEQ,'|')= NVL(p_indx(i),'|'));
```

Comment: why not have a unique constraint on (IEEXCO_SEQ, IEEXCO_DEPT_CODE). This way, whenever you are going to insert, for any duplicate records your insert will fail. You don't have to write extra conditions or queries to check it.

Comment: The question is why are you inserting a single row at a time? It appears that you are using a collection of a record and comparing each record to insert. Why not do a `single insert into` for all records and manage them with constraints and exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.
Do the insert, and respond to (ignore) the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception.

That's the safest on a concurrency front as if someone else has done the insert and not committed, the insert will wait on the locked record and then error when that other transaction commits (or succeed if the other transaction is rolled back).

Comment: This is the correct approach but does require the table has a unique constraint declared on IEEXCO_SEQ.

Answer (score -3):

The second method very fast,

```
INSERT...
SELECT
      Column_Name 
FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ..)
```

also, check the structure of a `unique key`